# Parallel Process Python Loop while writing to file

Tags: python, multithreading, loops, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

The question could be quite trivial, but I was wondering if anyone could help me parallel process this loop. There is a reference to "n" (row number) and a CSV which I print the answers too... I am unsure how to (if I need to) handle this "n" value between the parallelism?

I have googled a number of topics and checked stackoverflow for examples - I was hoping to use the multiprocessing library, but I'm happy to stand corrected if something else is better. My Python skill is relatively basic and I have never looked into parallel processing before.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from fitter import Fitter#, get_common_distributions, get_distributions
from fitter import get_common_distributions
from fitter import get_distributions
import os
import IPython

dataset = pd.read_csv("econ.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': pd.Series([], dtype='str'),
                   'Output': pd.Series([], dtype='str')})

n=0

for col in dataset.columns:

    spac = dataset[col].values
    f = Fitter(spac, distributions=get_distributions())
    f.fit()

    print(col,n)

    df.loc[n]=[col]+[f.get_best(method='sumsquare_error')]
    df.to_csv('dist.csv', index=False)

    n=n+1
    print(df)

    IPython.Application.instance().kernal.do_shutdown(True)
```

An example of the output file (dist.csv) is:

| Name | Output |
| --- | --- |
| SPAC | {'gennorm': {'beta': 1.1103780008768631, 'loc': 0.0977722086198811, 'scale': 0.8284342569644088}} |

Comment: writing in file in multiprocessing can make problems because two processes may try to write at the same time and they may write wrong data. It may need to send data back to main process and it should write all data. But multiprocessing use `pickle` file to send data from process to process and this need extra time.

Comment: using `expect: pass` can be the worst think. You may have some mistake/error in code but you can't see it. You could at least use `except Exception as ex: print(ex)` to see something when you will get error.

Comment: maybe you should write to file after `for`-loop. At this moment you write to file many times and this may also slowdown code.

Comment: Have you tried running this code?

Comment: I'm happy to remove the try/except - I dont require it anymore.

Comment: Yes, I have tried running the code - takes about 30sec per run. Which is fine but the number of columns exceeds 200 and the process slows etc. so I was looking to multiprocess in order to speed up. To be honest, I wouldn't be against writing a new csv to a folder each time and then combining all the files in that folder later (task would take seconds and would remove the "n" problem, if it is one)

Comment: @MikalFischer The code, as shown, is not runnable for various reasons (missing imports, invalid attribute, etc). Please provide a minimal reproducible example. You should also clarify why you're using IPython

Comment: I have updated the code to remove the except and try. 

The only input required should be, dataset = pd.read_csv("econ.csv"), which is just a csv with 200 columns and ~400 rows of entity connection data (digital signal processing data). If you like I can upload to a google sheet? However I think the file is irrelevant (can just run a random number down the column for the purpose). I have also added an example output in the question too.

Comment: If you want to parallelize this, you should parallelize the *fitting* procedure (which is the bottleneck) *not* the writing to file.  So, fit 1000 things in parallel, then write all of that (not in parallel) to file, then fit 1000 more things in parallel, etc.

Comment: this is easily parallelizable in a map-reduce way.  Look into joblib.